# Несколько datePicker на одной странице в динамической форме не работает, почему?

Tags: yii2

На странице динамическая форма где создаются несколько виджетов datePicker

```
<?= $form->field($modelAddress,  "[{$i}]date")-
>widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::className()) ?>
```

первый виджет работает, остальные нет, выбрать дату нельзя.

в исходнике страницы получается вот это

```
<input type="text" id="ordertemplate-0-date" name="OrderTemplate[0]
[date]" class="hasDatepicker" aria-invalid="true">
```

......

```
<input type="text" id="ordertemplate-1-date" name="OrderTemplate[1]
[date]" aria-invalid="true">
```

почему-то исчезает  class="hasDatepicker"    пробовал прописывать его явно, все равно не помогает, и в этом ли причина проблемы?

Может кто знает как решить эту лабуду,  пробовал и виджет от катрика,  тоже самое, первый срабатывает остальные нет (

Comment: За Yii и его виджеты точно не скажу, но вообще это стандартное поведение js, то есть вы динамически вызываете виджеты (видимо нажимая на +), но все последующие виджеты для js невидимы в DOM из-за динамики вызова.

Comment: Да, нажимаю на +, а есть варианты как это пофиксить?

Comment: Только читая мануалы или API, все равно ковыряние в исходном коде не поможет. А я, к сожалению, не гуру js, чтобы подсказать как перехватывать события

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.
Чтобы работали все добавляемые DatePicker Вам надо сначала принудительно удалить dataPicker, а потом заново, принудительно, инициализировать все видимые виджеты.
Выглядит это приблизительно так:

```
echo $form->field($model, '[0]date')->widget(DatePicker::className(),[
            'options' => [
                'data' => [
                    'picker' => 'datepicker'
                ]
            ]
     ])
```

а ниже, или в отдельном файле, будет такой js код:

```
$('#plus').on('click', function(){
   /* какой-то Ваш код */
   $('#testForm').find('.hasDatepicker').datepicker('destroy');
   $('#testForm').find('input[data-picker=datepicker]').datepicker();
   /* какой-то Ваш код */
})
```

Пришлось добавить параметр **"data-picker"**, так как при **"destroy"** удаляется класс **"hasDatepicker"**